# I Can't install python3-pip because it has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, software-installation, python3

So i entered
`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`
And i got

````
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate```
````

Comment: So please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1464711/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`